# Unsure how to run Celery under windows for periodic tasks

Tags: python, django, windows, celery, django-celery

I am having difficulty understanding how to run Celery after setting up some scheduled tasks.

Firstly, my project directory is structured as follows:

[image]

**`blogpodapi\api\__init__.py`** contains

```
from tasks import app
import celeryconfig
```

**`blogpodapi\api\celeryconfig.py`** contains

```
from datetime import timedelta

# Celery settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("api.tasks",)

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'write-test': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.addrandom',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=2),
        'args': (16000, 42)
    },
}
```

**`blogpodapi\api\tasks.py`** contains

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import random
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('blogpodapi')


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    r = x + y
    print "task arguments: {x}, {y}".format(x=x, y=y)
    print "task result: {r}".format(r=r)
    return r


@app.task
def addrandom(x, *args): # *args are not used, just there to be interchangable with add(x, y)
    y = random.randint(1,100)
    print "passing to add(x, y)"
    return add(x, y)
```

**`blogpodapi\blogpodapi\__init__.py`** contains

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app  # noqa
```

**`blogpodapi\blogpodapi\settings.py`** contains

```
...

# Celery settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("api.tasks",)

...
```

I run `celery -A blogpodapi worker --loglevel=info` in command prompt and get the following:

```
D:\blogpodapi>celery -A blogpodapi worker --loglevel=info

 -------------- celery@JM v3.1.23 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-8-6.2.9200
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         blogpodapi:0x348a940
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/1
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . api.tasks.add
  . api.tasks.addrandom
  . blogpodapi.celery.debug_task

[2016-08-13 13:01:51,108: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2016-08-13 13:01:52,122: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-08-13 13:01:55,138: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:265: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2016-08-13 13:02:00,157: WARNING/MainProcess] c:\python27\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:265: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2016-08-13 13:02:27,790: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@JM ready.
```

I then run `celery -A blogpodapi beat` in command prompt and get the following:

```
D:\blogpodapi>celery -A blogpodapi beat
celery beat v3.1.23 (Cipater) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379/0
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
[2016-08-13 13:02:51,937: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
```

For some reason, I can't seem to view my periodic tasks being logged. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE: here is my celery.py...**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'blogpodapi.settings')

from django.conf import settings  # noqa

app = Celery('blogpodapi')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Comment: What exactly is in your `celery.py`? You've shown the contents of all other files except `celery.py`

Comment: I must have forgotten. Just updated the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run celery beat with the celery settings file

```
celery -A blogpodapi.celery beat --loglevel=INFO
```

Comment: How do you do that

Comment: isntead of ```celery -A blogpodapi beat``` run the command above

Comment: Do I just run that or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: @methuselah did that fix it?

Comment: @methuselah you need that for celery beat to send the scheduled tasks to the exchange. You also need the celery worker to run. So start the worker first then start celery beat.

Comment: celery does not support beat  in Windows